# best 3 android phone available in india for application developer (testing purpose)?

Tags: android

Give suggestion  which phone having android os is best for testing purpose available in india?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to buy the Android Dev phones which can be Shipped to India.
Otherwise choose from any phones in the supported list of [Cyanogenmod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Main_Page) and you should be able to make them your developer phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mail proxy services to order a Nexus from the US.

Otherwise just get a popular one with plenty of inputs. Popular models are more likely to be supported by the community.

I think the better question to ask is `What makes a good development phone?`, as this question won't be of any use to people in a year.

Comment: Availability of Android phones in India is still a problem. Where Motorola, Samsung and HTC are releasing a new phone almost every week, we don't get to see any of them. PLUS, they're all quite costly too. costing around 25k bucks.. so one has to think before going for the hunt ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think HTC Desire/Motorola Milestone [HDPI screen],HTC wildfire [LDPI screen] and one phone having mdpi screen size may be some LG/Samsung Phone can be good for testing. All this devices are available in India.

I'm suggesting HTC phones because this devices readily gets latest Android updates. Also Its nice to have devices from different vendors as it will be helpful to test device specific behaviours/issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a phone with nice Processor, big screen and a keyboard.

For that I will consider Moto Droid.
Its nice and is also supported by Cyanogen.

Else you can also get Samsung Galaxy S which also has got Cyanogen support.

these will cost more than 20 thousand bucks.

You can also think about Samsung Galaxy 3 or 5 if budget is an issue.

Comment: Avoid the Galaxy S, and anything Samsung really. They have GPS and lag issues which will never be truly resolved. I own a Galaxy S and I really regret buying it.

Comment: Wow.. thanks for telling this.. I won't buy one now. What about Sony devices?